# Star Glyphicon not working, shows an arrow instead

Tags: html, glyphicons

When i use :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

instead of star, its displaying an arrow,
when i use search glyphicon, its displaying a rhombus. Few glyph are not getting displayed.

```
   bootstrap.min.css
   bootstrap-theme.min.css
   bootstrap-theme.css
   bootstrap.css  
   http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
   bootstrap.min.js
```

Can somebody please help?

Thank you

Comment: I have included all the bootstrap files i mentioned above.

Comment: Is this issue on every browser or just specific?

Comment: Seems browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```html
<link href = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<div class="the-icons">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</div>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/b8rya0L4/)

Make Sure to include `bootstrap.min.css` Link is [Here](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)